# Generate JavaScript code from string to set a property in the generated code and then return it

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vuejs3

I have had some difficulties using .vue components with the vue.js cdn on my apache server. I am using PHP for routing and what you else use PHP for and then I thought wanted to use vue for generating the html. I quickly learned that importing .vue on the apache server with the vue.js cdn was not possible because it got blocked due to the MIME type.

So I began creating my own .vue to javascript converter/generator (got help from ChatGPT but it's currently down).

I have my website hosted at one.com and I don't want to switch hosting. Their servers does not support NodeJS and that's why I dont use NodeJS for this but the cdn instead.

I thought it would be cool to have my own implementation of .vue since I like to do my projects bigger than they needs to be xD

This is my vue code to create the vue app.

```
<div id="top-menu">
    
    <test></test>
    <common-input-field-group label="Test" placeholder="Snask"></common-input-field-group>
</div>

<script type="module">
    import TopMainMenu from '/resources/js/components/TopMainMenu.js'
    //import Test from '/resources/js/components/Test.vue'
    //import Test from '/resources/js/components/Test.js'

    import ComponentImporter from '/resources/js/VueComponetImporter.js'
    const component = ComponentImporter("/resources/js/components/CommonInputFieldGroup.vue")
    
    //const component = await axios.get("/resources/js/components/CommonInputFieldGroup.html")

    const app = Vue.createApp({
        data() {
            return {
               
            }
        },
        methods: {
            
        },
        components: {
            CommonInputFieldGroup: component
        }
    })

    app.mount('#top-menu')
</script>
```

This is the code ChatGPT suggested. The only thing I knew how to use here was axios the rest I had to get help to figure out how to do but the idea of doing it this way is my own.

```
const generateExecutableCode = (script, template) => {
    return new Function(`
      ${script}
      exportDefault.template = \`${template}\`
      return exportDefault
    `)
  }

export default async function ComponentImporter (path) {
    return await axios.get(path).then(response => {
        const data = response.data

        let template = data.match(/<template>([\s\S]+?)<\/template>/)[1]
        let script = data.match(/<script>([\s\S]+?)<\/script>/)[1]

        const executeableCode = generateExecutableCode(script, template);
        return executeableCode()
    })
}
```

And here is my .vue file content

```
<template>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>{{label}}</label>
        <input type="type" class="form-control" :placeholder="placeholder" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
    props: {
        label: String,
        placeholder: String
    },
    data(){
        return {
            message: "Hello World!"
        }
    },
    methods: {
        submit(){
            alert("Fisk")
        }
    },
    template: null
}
</script>
```

This error code I get when running the code
[Image of the error message the code gives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeZKB.png)

The error message in text:

```
    Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module
    generateExecutableCode http://skimspots.arpa/resources/js/VueComponetImporter.js:3
    ComponentImporter http://skimspots.arpa/resources/js/VueComponetImporter.js:17
    promise callback*ComponentImporter http://skimspots.arpa/resources/js/VueComponetImporter.js:11
    <anonymous> http://skimspots.arpa/:31
VueComponetImporter.js:5:4
    ComponentImporter http://skimspots.arpa/resources/js/VueComponetImporter.js:20
    AsyncFunctionThrow self-hosted:811
    (Async: async)
    <anonymous> http://skimspots.arpa/:31
```

One of the times I also got the error message that it was an ambiguous export return or something.

Comment: ChatGPT ***doesn’t write code***. It generates text that statistically speaking *looks* like code. You can’t rely on the tool to provide accurate answers to coding questions and any code output it generates should be taken with a huge grain of salt.

Comment: I know. I have been programming for 13 years but I just could not find any solution on stackoverflow, github and other articles so I tried to see what ChatGPT would suggest. But it did not understand my request fully at all. It kept suggesting the same solutions that failed.